# AngularJS and jQuery Calendar Directive to work when clicking on Bootstrap glyphicon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

So far I have created a directive for my calendar using AngularJS and jQuery. When the user selects the input box, jQuery's datepicker will pop-up. I am also trying to make it so that the user can click on Bootstrap's 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar' to pop-up jQuery's datepicker. I am currently stuck and don't know what to do. I have created a jsfiddle so you guys can see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3696/

Here is the code sample:

```
<div ng-app="App">
   <div class="input-group"> 
     <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
     <input type="text" name="startDate" calendar ng-model="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" ng-minlength="10"></input>
   </div>
 </div>



  var app = angular.module('App', [])
  app.directive('calendar', function () {
      return {
             require: 'ngModel',
             link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
              $(el).datepicker({
                  minDate: 0,
                  dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',
                  onSelect: function (dateText) {
                      scope.$apply(function () {
                          ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                      });
                  }
              });
          }
      };
  })
```

Comment: If you dont wish to incorporate the glyphicon as part of a template for your directive then you can add an attribute to your directive which will force the JQuery calendar to show. Watch it with an attr.observe in your directive and modify it on your glyhpicon click.

Answer (score 0):

Example below based on your fiddle. It adds a data attribute which drives a call to JQuerys show  method. I've just let the 'show' value hang out on $rootScope for the sake of brevity. You won't wish to be doing that for your final code.

This kind of data-attribute driven function mapping works well for any function or set of functions you wish to expose which operate in a binary manner, **on-off**, **show-hide** etc.

Plunker example... http://plnkr.co/edit/PHzaYP?p=preview

```
<body>
<button ng-click="show=!show">Show={{show}}</button>
<input data-show="{{show}}" 
       type="text" 
       name="startDate" 
       calendar2 
       ng-model="startDate" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" 
       ng-minlength="10"></input>

<script>

angular.element(document).ready(function(){

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('calendar2', function () {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {

            attr.$observe("show",function(val){
                if(val=='true'){
                    $(el).datepicker( "show" );
                }
                else{
                    $(el).datepicker( "hide" );
                }
            });

            $(el).datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
              });
            }
          };
        });

    angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, mccainz! I appreciate it. However, I tried copying and pasting the code on JSFiddle and I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the updated JsFiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3710/

Comment: Updated the script to match a working plunker which demonstrates the method I described. http://plnkr.co/edit/PHzaYP?p=preview

Comment: And finally, a working fiddle based on your original example.  http://jsfiddle.net/mccainz/U3pVM/3726/

Comment: Thank you very much, mccainz! I can see the working fiddle. However, there is one issue I encountered while opening and closing the datepicker using your show toggle approach. When I click on the glyphicon, {{show}} returns true and the datepicker reveals, which is great. But when I decide to close the datepicker by clicking anywhere outside, {{show}} still remains true. As a result, If I want to reveal the datepicker again, I would have to click on the glyphicon twice. Is there a way to make {{show}} also return false when the user closes the datepicker by clicking outside?